# Can not add rows using datatable.js Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, datatables

I tried to create table using datatable.js ajax. 
I'm getting data from webmethod , but, result is not adding into the tables.

> JS Method

```
 function getMyData() {
            alert('d');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "AssignHistory.aspx/getModemAssign ",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: buildMyDatatable,
                error:
                    function (msg) {
                        alert(msg.status + " " + msg.statusText);
                    }
            });

            function buildMyDatatable(result) { 
                var data = JSON.stringify(result.d);
                $('#gvAssgin').dataTable({
                    retrieve: true,
                    JSON:data,
                    columns: [
                            { data: "ModemId" },
                            { data: "ModemName" }
                    ]
                }); 
            }
        }
```

> HTML Code

```
   <table id="gvAssgin">
      <thead>
        <tr>
             <th>
                   Modem ID 
             </th>
             <th>
                   Modem Name 
             </th>
         </tr>
   </thead>
```

Result I'm getting is,
[image]

waiting for replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct option of JavaScript sourced data is [`data`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/data). Also there is no need to generate JSON again with `JSON.stringify(result.d)`, just pass the array to jQuery DataTables.

See the corrected code below:

```
$('#gvAssgin').dataTable({
    data: result.d,
    columns: [
       { data: "ModemId" },
       { data: "ModemName" }
    ]
});
```

Comment: thanks it helps me.I have one more query, that i trying to create a check box inside the Datatable column and i need to set data value to that check box

Comment: @KarthikTv, regarding checkboxes, please see our article [Row selection using checkboxes and Select extension](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-row-selection-using-checkboxes-and-select-extension/) and [How to add a checkbox column](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-add-a-checkbox-column/)

Comment: Thanks you so much. I have posted another one question similar to this. can you please Look into that. It will save my day.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35219337/can-not-add-rows-datatable-js-sajaxsource-ajax-call